# SharePoint 2010 CU update

Tags: 2010, cumulative-update, configuration-wizard

My question is regarding SP 2010 CU update. I have two farms that work together. 1st Farm is 1 App and 2 Webs. 2 nd farm is 6 Apps that primarily has Search and other applications. App1 in the first farm is CA for that farm and App1 of the second farm is CA for that farm. I do know that when I install CU, I can do it on all the servers simultaneously. But, when running the Config wizard, how do I prioritize since two servers are CA?

- Reboot the 1st farm CA server and run the config wizard followed by rebooting the 2nd farm CA server and running the config wizard?
- Reboot the 1st farm CA server and run the config wizard followed by rebooting the WFE's in the same farm and running the config wizard and then coming to the 2nd farm servers?

Which of the above is the right way to make sure they are correct?

Vj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of patching or running the Config Wizard does not matter. You can reboot each server one by one/run the Config Wizard one by one to maintain high availability, if that is the goal.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. Yes, high availability is the primary goal. My only concern was since there are two CA servers, I was wondering whether the CA servers needs to be done first (PSconfiged) before getting to other servers in the farm.

Comment: No, you can run the Config Wizard on the FEs first, if you wanted to.